# Is it possible to stack elements along z-axis without using position:absolute now?

Tags: html, css, frontend

I know this wasn't until a few years ago but is it possible now? Can we get any of the newer css3 properties like flexbox, calc(), viewport units and z-index to work together and produce a stack of cards along the z-axis?

Flexbox supports only the main and cross axis so I'm not sure if it is worthwhile to explore this path. But here is want I to be able to do:

Stack `divs` on top of each other like this: http://output.jsbin.com/nefufoy

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <style>
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="page red"> </div>
  <div class="page blue"> </div>
  <div class="page green"> </div>
  <div class="page yellow"> </div>
</body>
</html>
```

In `css`:

```
html, body {
    height: 100 vh;
    width: 100% ;
    background: wheat;
    position: relative;
}

.page {
    position: absolute;
    width: 22vh;
    height: 30vh;
}

.red {
    background: red;
    z-index: 0;
    top: 29vh;
    left: 45vw;

}

.blue {
    background: blue;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 31vh;
    left: 43vw;

}

.green {
    background: green;
    z-index: 2;
    top: 33vh;
    left: 41vw;

}

.yellow {
    background: yellow;
    z-index: 3;
    top: 35vh;
    left: 39vw;

}
```

Comment: You could probably do that with 3D transforms.  No other feature will help you.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do here at all. Can you elaborate on the exact effect you're trying to achieve? What you posted in your example link is possible simply using negative margins...

Comment: z-index also works with other kinds of positioning: fixed and relative.

Comment: `position:absolute` is simple no doubt, but it does introduce long-frames and triggers re-layout easily. Not very efficient per se.